# how to push exploded array(Group_Concat Result) to another array

Tags: php, mysql

To return array in `json_encode` format, for single row, simply we push element as follow. For example

```
$query = "SELECT expenses.ttl AS name, expenses.amnt AS amnt FROM expenses";
$result = $con->prepare($query) or die($con->error);
$result->execute();
$data = array();
foreach($result as $row){
    $data[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($data)
```

But how to push `GROUP_CONCAT` exploded array to this (next) array. For example

```
$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(salary.ttl,',',purchase.ttl,',',extra.ttl) AS name, 
        CONCAT(SUM(salary.amnt),',',SUM(purchase.amnt),',',SUM(COALESCE(extra.amnt,'0'))) AS amnt
        FROM salary LEFT JOIN..."
$result = $con->prepare($query) or die($con->error);
$result->execute();
while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $name = explode(',',$row['name']);
    $amnt = explode(',',$row['amnt']);

    //how to push these specific value to array $data As above.
}

print json_encode($data)
```

Comment: What does `$ttl` and `$amnt` look like? Can you show a `var_dump`? What is your expected result? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `$data[] = [$name, $amnt];`?

Comment: @Sean, yeah I am searching like `$data[] = [$name, $amnt];`, So it will contains Group_concat result.